# How to restart the server?

Tags: server, virtual-machine, restart, reboot

I have reboot the server (in which there is a VM with linux). The problem is that after the reboot (I've used the sudo reboot -h now command) the system doesn't go.
So when I try to open it by terminal it returns: ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: No route to host
How can I resolve it? Thanks to everyone for help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

When you reboot the (I guess) ESXi host, the VM inside will not boot by themselves unless you change the settings on the vsphere client which is "Startup/Shutdown VM with the host".

If ESXi, log in to the host using the vsphere client and boot your VM. Then, go to the settings and search that option.

Comment: Thanks! there isn't a way just by terminal?

Comment: You did not specify anything about your server, I personally have not downvoted your answer but some more info would be really appreciate to know what the issue can be. One of the most used is the ESXi, and I use it and I know that if you reboot the host, the VM do not boot with it by default. Other OS for virtualization may act at the same method. But still, we do not know anything of what you are using and what exactly you rebooted

Comment: Thank you!! You're right, the problem that I neither know more about the server, t was done by another one person at the office.